# Python Tkinter listbox with MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql, listbox, tkinter, mysql-python

It's my first program in python and I'm trying to create a program that will interface a MySql address book with a asterisk server and make a call. 
The "asterisk code part" is ok, I will add later, but the problem is that I have a listbox in Tkinter and I would like to fill it with values retrieved from a mysqldb query. 
I only can add a single value to the listbox, but if I make a print the results is correct.
How can I solve this? I imagine that I will have to do a for loop.
Later I will have to know how select a value from the list and store in a variable.

```
from Tkinter import *
import MySQLdb
root = Tk()
root.title("PyCall")
myContainer = Frame(root)
myContainer.pack(side=TOP, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost",port=3306, user="root", passwd="mypass", db="test" )
cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM utenti")
db.commit()

numrows = int(cursor.rowcount)
for x in range(0,numrows):
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    print row[1]

listbox = Listbox(root)
listbox.pack()
listbox.insert(END, row[1])

root.mainloop()
db.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's your first program in Python, you're off to a good start! Your question really has little to do with MySQL, and you seem to have a good handle on that, so I'll leave that alone and just focus on the Tkinter issues you are having. I don't have a MySQL database to test with anyway :)

It's generally a good idea in GUI applications, at least in Tkinter, to setup your own application class with a Tk root frame as the application's master container. The reason for this is that GUIs are a always a bit of slight of hand, they are only a facade for real application data, and that real data needs someplace to live. By creating your own application class, you have a home for that data via `self`.

Okay, enough with all the boring stuff, let's just build something:

```
import Tkinter


class Application(Tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master.minsize(width=256, height=256)
        self.master.config()
        self.pack()

        self.main_frame = Tkinter.Frame()

        self.some_list = [
            'One',
            'Two',
            'Three',
            'Four'
        ]

        self.some_listbox = Tkinter.Listbox(self.main_frame)

        # bind the selection event to a custom function
        # Note the absence of parentheses because it's a callback function
        self.some_listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.listbox_changed)
        self.some_listbox.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        self.main_frame.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

        # insert our items into the list box
        for i, item in enumerate(self.some_list):
            self.some_listbox.insert(i, item)

        # make a label to show the selected item
        self.some_label = Tkinter.Label(self.main_frame, text="Welcome to SO!")
        self.some_label.pack(side='top')

        # not really necessary, just make things look nice and centered
        self.main_frame.place(in_=self.master, anchor='c', relx=.5, rely=.5)

    def listbox_changed(self, *args, **kwargs):
        selection_index = self.some_listbox.curselection()
        selection_text = self.some_listbox.get(selection_index, selection_index)
        self.some_label.config(text=selection_text)

root = Tkinter.Tk()
app = Application(root)
app.mainloop()
```

Hope this helps, and have fun building GUIs!

Comment: Thanks Pathétique your code is working very well! Now I must insert in self.some_list [...] the query or the query results. I've tried but without success. Please help a poor noob!

Comment: I just used a regular Python list, you can add items using `append`. [See the Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).

Comment: The interpreter tells me that listbox has not 'append' attribute

Comment: `self.some_list` is a Python list object and can be added to using `append`, `self.some_listbox` is a Tkinter.Listbox object and items can be added using `insert` given the index where you want to insert the string and the string to insert...like in my for loop above.

Comment: The problem is that if I use `append` or `insert` with Mysql it insert only the last value of the column I choose.

Comment: Solved! I changed the code in this way:

`self.some_list = [

            'ADDRESS BOOK'
        ]
        db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost",port=3306, user="root", passwd="mypass", db="test" )
        cursor = db.cursor()

        cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM users")
        db.commit()

        numrows = int(cursor.rowcount)
        for i in range(0,numrows):
            row = cursor.fetchone()
            if (row):
                self.some_list.append(row[0])`

Thank you for the help! I am really grateful